# Ionic 2 - List the Array items from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ionic2

I got the following output from JSON response(console.log(cluster in **cal.ts**).

[image: Console Ouput of console.log(cluster in cal.ts)]

Now i need to list only 5 element names which is in 3:Array(5)(please refer Picture). I tried the following code with the error

```
  caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

**cal.html**

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let element of finalresult" >      
  <p >element.name</p>
</ion-item>
```

**cal.ts**

```
getdata(){

this.loading.present();

this.httpProvider.getJsonData().subscribe(

  result => {

    this.newsData=result;
    let cluster = {};
    result.forEach( r => {
    r.category_ids.forEach( id => {
    if(!cluster[id])
      cluster[id] = [];   
    cluster[id].push(r);
  });
});  
this.finalresult=cluster;
console.log(cluster);
  },
  err =>{
    console.error("Error : "+err);
  } ,
  () => {
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }
);
}
```

My JSON Result

```
 [{"product_id":"40","sku":"HOS001","name":"Turmeric Powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","3"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"41","sku":"HOS001-20 grms","name":"Turmeric Powder-20 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"42","sku":"HOS001-100 grms","name":"Turmeric Powder-100 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"43","sku":"HOS001-50 grms","name":"Turmeric Powder-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"44","sku":"HOS002","name":"Coriander Powder ","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","3"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"47","sku":"HOS003","name":"Chilli Powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","3"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"48","sku":"HOS003-50 grms","name":"Chilli Powder-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"49","sku":"HOS003-100 grms","name":"Chilli Powder-100 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"50","sku":"HOS003-500 g","name":"Chilli Powder-500 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"51","sku":"HOS003-20 grms","name":"Chilli Powder-20 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"52","sku":"HOS004","name":"Cumin Powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","3"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"53","sku":"HOS004-50 grms","name":"Cumin Powder-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"54","sku":"HOS004-500 g","name":"Cumin Powder-500 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"55","sku":"HOS005","name":"Pepper Powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","3"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"56","sku":"HOS005-50 grms","name":"Pepper Powder-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"57","sku":"HOS005-10 grms","name":"Pepper Powder-10 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"58","sku":"HOS002-20 grms","name":"Coriander Powder -20 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"59","sku":"HOS002-50 grms","name":"Coriander Powder -50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"60","sku":"HOS002-100 grms","name":"Coriander Powder -100 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"61","sku":"HOS002-500 g","name":"Coriander Powder -500 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"62","sku":"HOS006","name":"Kulambu Chilli powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"63","sku":"HOS006-50 grms","name":"Kulambu Chilli powder-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"64","sku":"HOS007","name":"Sambar Powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"66","sku":"HOS007-50 grms","name":"Sambar Powder-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"67","sku":"HOS008","name":"Rasam Powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"68","sku":"HOS008-50 grms","name":"Rasam Powder-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"69","sku":"HOS009","name":"Idly chutney Powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"70","sku":"HOS009-50 grms","name":"Idly chutney Powder-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"71","sku":"HOS010","name":"Garam Masala ","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"72","sku":"HOS010-50 grms","name":"Garam Masala -50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"73","sku":"HOS011","name":"Curry masala powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"74","sku":"HOS011-50 grms","name":"Curry masala powder-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"75","sku":"HOS011-100 grms","name":"Curry masala powder-100 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"76","sku":"HOS012","name":"Happyos Veg Briyani Masala","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"78","sku":"HOS013","name":"Chicken briyani masala","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"80","sku":"HOS014","name":"Mutton Briyani masala","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"82","sku":"HOS012-50 grms","name":"Veg Briyani Masala-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"83","sku":"HOS013-50 grms","name":"Chicken briyani masala-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"84","sku":"HOS014-50 grms","name":"Mutton Briyani masala-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"85","sku":"HOS015","name":"Chilli Chicken Masala","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"86","sku":"HOS015-50 grms","name":"Chilli Chicken Masala-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"87","sku":"HOS016 ","name":"Chicken Masala","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"88","sku":"HOS016 -50 grms","name":"Chicken Masala-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"89","sku":"HOS016 -20 grms","name":"Chicken Masala-20 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"90","sku":"HOS016 -100 grms","name":"Chicken Masala-100 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"91","sku":"HOS016 -250 g jar","name":"Chicken Masala-250 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"92","sku":"HOS017","name":"Mutton Masala","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"93","sku":"HOS017-50 grms","name":"Mutton Masala-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"94","sku":"HOS017-100 g jar","name":"Mutton Masala-100 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"95","sku":"HOS017-250 g jar","name":"Mutton Masala-250 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"96","sku":"HOS016 -100 g jar","name":"Chicken Masala-100 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"97","sku":"HOS018","name":"Fish fry Masala","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","5"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"98","sku":"HOS018-50 grms","name":"Fish fry Masala-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"99","sku":"HOS019","name":"Asafoetida Powder","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","4"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"100","sku":"HOS019-50 grms","name":"Asafoetida Powder-50 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"101","sku":"HOS020","name":"Mango Thokku Pickle","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"102","sku":"HOS020-200 g","name":"Mango Thokku Pickles-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"103","sku":"HOS021","name":"Coriander leaves Pickle","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"104","sku":"HOS021-200 g","name":"Coriander leaves Pickle-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"105","sku":"HOS022","name":"Ginger Pickle ","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"106","sku":"HOS022-200 g","name":"Ginger Pickle -200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"107","sku":"HOS023","name":"Sweet Mango Pickle","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"108","sku":"HOS023-200 g","name":"Sweet Mango Pickle-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"109","sku":"HOS024","name":"Pudina Pickle","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"110","sku":"HOS024-200 g","name":"Pudina Pickle-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"112","sku":"HOS026","name":"Tomato Pickle","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"113","sku":"HOS026-200 g","name":"Tomato Pickle-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"114","sku":"HOS027","name":"Lime Pickle","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"115","sku":"HOS027-200 g","name":"Lime Pickle-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"116","sku":"HOS028","name":"Garlic Pickle","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"117","sku":"HOS028-200 g","name":"Garlic Pickle-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"118","sku":"HOS029","name":"Mango Pickle","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"119","sku":"HOS029-200 g","name":"Mango Pickle-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"120","sku":"HOS030","name":"Bitterlime Pickle","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"121","sku":"HOS030-200 g","name":"Bitterlime Pickle-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"122","sku":"HOS031","name":"Vathakulambu Mix","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","8"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"123","sku":"HOS031-200 g","name":"Vathakulambu Mix-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"124","sku":"HOS032","name":"Puliyodharai Mix","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","8"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"125","sku":"HOS032-200 g","name":"Puliyodharai Mix-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"126","sku":"HOS033","name":"Mixed veg Pickle","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","6"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"127","sku":"HOS033-200 g","name":"Mixed veg Pickle-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"128","sku":"HOS038","name":"Appalam","set":"9","type":"configurable","category_ids":["2","9"],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"129","sku":"HOS038-100 grms","name":"Appalam-100 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"130","sku":"HOS038-150 g","name":"Appalam-150 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"131","sku":"HOS038-200 g","name":"Appalam-200 g","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"132","sku":"HOS031-200 g-Packet","name":"Vathakulambu Mix-200 g-Packet","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"133","sku":"HOS031-100 grms-Packet","name":"Vathakulambu Mix-100 grms-Packet","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"134","sku":"HOS031-10 grms-Pet Jar","name":"Vathakulambu Mix-100 grms-Pet Jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"135","sku":"HOS001-100 g jar","name":"Turmeric Powder-100 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"136","sku":"HOS001-250 g jar","name":"Turmeric Powder-250 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"137","sku":"HOS001-500 g jar","name":"Turmeric Powder-500 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"138","sku":"HOS002-250 g jar","name":"Coriander Powder -250 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"139","sku":"HOS002-100 g jar","name":"Coriander Powder -100 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"140","sku":"HOS003-100 g jar","name":"Chilli Powder-100 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"141","sku":"HOS003-250 g jar","name":"Chilli Powder-250 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"142","sku":"HOS006-100 g jar","name":"Kulambu Chilli powder-100 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"143","sku":"HOS006-250 g jar","name":"Kulambu Chilli powder-250 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"144","sku":"HOS007-100 grms","name":"Sambar Powder-100 grms","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"145","sku":"HOS007-100 g jar","name":"Sambar Powder-100 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"146","sku":"HOS007-250 g jar","name":"Sambar Powder-250 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"147","sku":"HOS007-500 g jar","name":"Sambar Powder-500 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"148","sku":"HOS008-100 g jar","name":"Rasam Powder-100 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"149","sku":"HOS008-250 g jar","name":"Rasam Powder-250 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"150","sku":"HOS008-500 g jar","name":"Rasam Powder-500 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"151","sku":"HOS009-100 g jar","name":"Idly chutney Powder-100 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"152","sku":"HOS009-250 g jar","name":"Idly chutney Powder-250 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"153","sku":"HOS009-500 g jar","name":"Idly chutney Powder-500 g jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"154","sku":"HOS019-20 grms-Pet Jar","name":"Asafoetida Powder-20 grms-Pet Jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"155","sku":"HOS019-10 grms-Pet Jar","name":"Asafoetida Powder-10 grms-Pet Jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]},{"product_id":"156","sku":"HOS022-200 g-Pet Jar","name":"Ginger Pickle -200 g-Pet Jar","set":"9","type":"simple","category_ids":[],"website_ids":["1"]}]
```

Final Result should look similar to the following image. But instead of the items, It should display Turmeric Powder, Coriander Powder...

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because your variable cluster is an Object and not an array.

Just change

```
let cluster = {};
```

to

```
let cluster = [];
```

And then change your ngFor accordingly like

```
<ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let element of finalresult[3]" >      
  <p>element.name</p>
</ion-item>
```

EDIT:

I think the finalresult variable does not have the data yet. So try this

```
let finalresult = []; //where you have declared the variable

this.httpProvider.getJsonData().subscribe(

        result => {

            this.newsData=result;
            let cluster = [];
            let i = 0;
            result.forEach( r => {
                i++;
                let j = 0;
                r.category_ids.forEach( id => {
                    j++;
                    if(!cluster[id])
                        cluster[id] = [];
                    cluster[id].push(r);
                });
                if(i == result.length && j == r.category_ids.length) this.finalresult=cluster;
            });
            console.log(cluster);
        },
        err =>{
            console.error("Error : "+err);
        } ,
        () => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
        }
    );
```

Comment: Did. But Error "Cannot read property '3' of undefined and the browser console output changed to          (10) [undefined × 2, Array(33), Array(5), Array(1), Array(13), Array(11), undefined × 1, Array(2), Array(1)]2: Array(33)3: Array(5)0: Objectcategory_ids: Array(2)name: "Turmeric Powder"product_id: "40"set: "9"sku: "HOS001"type: "configurable"website_ids: Array(1)__proto__: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Objectlength: 5__proto__: Array(0)4: Array(1)5: Array(13)6: Array(11)8: Array(2)9: Array(1)length: 10__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Thank you very much Saksham Gupta.

Answer (score 0):

Your collection should be an array, right now you have an object consists of two arrays. you need to have a nested **`*ngFor`** and you need to have **`{{}}`**

```
<ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let element of finalresult" >      
  <p *ngFor="let mydetail of element " >{{mydetail.name}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Tried. But again error.   Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: how does your finalresult look like?

Comment: Final Output Updated

Comment: is not the result there?

Comment: No . Error is      " Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"

Answer (score 0):

By using ***ngFor="let element of finalresult"**, you're asking it to loop through the complete json **finalresult** which is an **Object**. As you said you only need to fetch particular array element from the result, you can try passing the key or index of that element.

So your *ngFor will now be, `*ngFor="let element of finalresult[3]"`

You can check out the concept of pipes if you want to further manipulate data.

Comment: Error : Error in ./Calendar class Calendar - caused by: Cannot read property '3' of undefined

Comment: Try finalresult?[3], it reads only if the object is defined. Also what is the datatype of your finalresult?